# Subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I am pretty confused right now with this. There should be a subgroup of $S_n$ with order x. So for example, for which n does $S_n$ contain a subgroup of order 60?
What about if we are looking for a **cyclic** subgroup of order 60?

Comment: I am pretty sure that determining the smallest $n$ for which $S_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G$ is a very hard problem; possibly even open. See this MO thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/smallest-permutation-representation-of-a-finite-group

Comment: What about $n$ generally? Without looking for the smallest $n$?

Comment: Well, if $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ then surely it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{n+1}$ and so on. So "smallest" is really the only interesting one; anything else is probably best thought of as a bound on the smallest. Cayley's theorem gives a bound, of course, but it is probably very weak.

Comment: Cayley's theorem guarantees any group $G$ embeds into the symmetric group $S_G$. That is, any group of order $n$ embeds into the symmetric group $S_n$. Given a natural number $m$, the smallest $n$ for which $S_n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $m$ is obtained by minimizing $(n_1+\cdots+n_k)!$ subject to the condition ${\rm lcm}(n_1,\cdots,n_k)=m$. Also, try not to word your questions sloppily - saying "there should be a subgroup of Sn with order x" doesn't make sense without saying what x is. You should say e.g. "given an x, there is an n for which Sn has a subgroup of order x."

Comment: If $n\geq 3+4+5=12$, $S_n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $60$: take the subgroup generated by an element of cycle type $(3,4,5)$. If $n<12$, $S_n$ has no cyclic subgroup of order $60$, since no element of  $S_n$ has order $60$.

Answer (score 3):

In general it is not easy to determine the values of $x$ in which $S_n$ has a subgroup of order $x$. For the cyclic case it is equivalent to find $x$ such that $S_n$ has an *element* of order $x$, which is quite straightforward:

if $m_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ are distinct positive integers and $\sum{m_i} \le n$ then for any subgroup $I$ of $\{1,...,k\}$ the group $S_n$ has an element (cyclic subgroup) of order $x = lcm (m_j )_{j \in I}$.  For example in $S_9$, we have elements of orders $1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ,8,9, 10,12,14,15,20$.

Comment: There's also an element of order $10$.

Comment: Yes, considering 2 and 5.